# Further optimization with numpy using einsum for stacked matrix-vector multiplication

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray, dot-product

I have a relatively straightforward case of "particle propagation" using linear matrix transformation.

My distribution of particles is basically a set ('bunch') of 5-dimensional vectors. It contains typically 100k to 1M such vectors.

Each of these vectors has to be multiplied by a matrix.

The solution I came up with so far is as follow.

The particles are created like this, the covariance matrix is shown here as diagonal, but it is for the sake of a relatively simple example:

```
# Edit: I now use np.random_intel linking to MKL for improved performances
d = np.random.multivariate_normal(
    [0.0,
     0.0,
     0.0,
     0.0,
     0.0
     ],
    np.array([
        [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1]
    ]),
    int(1e5)
)
```

The propagation matrix is simply

```
D = np.array([[1, 10, 0, 0], 
          [0, 1, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 1, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

And the solution I have with `einsum` is

```
r = np.einsum('ij,kj->ik', d[:, 0:4], D)
```

(note that here I slide to get only the first four coordinates of the vectors but unrelated reasons).

> Is there a way to make this significantly faster?

I do not have a clear view on all the details but here are some thoughts:

- `einsum` by default does not call BLAS but uses internal SSE optimizations, is there a way to express my problem with pure BLAS calls that would make it faster?
- Apparently recent versions of `einsum` of an `optimize` option that can be turned on to fall-back to BLAS calls in a wider variety of cases. I tried and it does not change the execution time.
- Would it be better with PyPy and numpy?

---

I tested @Divakar suggestion and it is indeed quite faster (10M particles):

```
%%timeit
r = d[:, 0:4].dot(D.T)
# 541 ms ± 9.44 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

compared to my initial

```
%%timeit -n 1 -r 1
r = np.einsum('ij,kj->ik', d[:, 0:4], D, optimize=True)
# 1.74 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
```

---

A directly related question that might impact the final answer:

> How can I deal with 'lost' particles?

After a single particle-by-particle matrix multiplication, I will be checking on the upper bounds of some coordinates, for example (`r` being the result of the previous step:

```
selected = (r[:, 0] < 0.1) & (r[:, 1] < 0.1)
ind = np.where(selected)
r[ind]
```

Then apply the next round of matrix multiplication of `r[ind]`.

A few things are not clear to me:

- is this the most efficient?
- doesn't it create too many copies around?
- wouldn't be better to "keep" the non-selected particles (and multiply them anyway) while keeping track of the fact that their are lost (via a mask)? That's a lot more multiplications but that could keep everything in a single object, with no further allocation and keeping everything aligned?

Comment: Use `d[:, 0:4].dot(D.T)`.

Comment: @Divakar: It does indeed improve things but a factor ~4, thanks! I'll edit my question to include a sub-question about masks, as this part was apparently quite trivial.

Comment: @CedricH.  Have your matrix `d` in **C-order** and  `D.T` in **fortran order** for some more optimization. That should make your code at least 2x faster :)

Comment: @CedricH. since axis 1 access is cheap in *C-order* whereas axis 0 access is cheaper *fortran order*, we'd like to have the matrices in appropriate order!

Comment: @kmario23 Thanks but not sure what you mean exactly. Something I can further improve from Divakar's suggestion?

Comment: @CedricH. are you open to considering frameworks like **PyTorch**? You can harness the power of GPU which will make your code much much faster, may be around 10x improvement :) **CuPy** is another option - which utilizes Cuda!

Comment: @CedricH. I added an answer based on PyTorch which will make your computation orders of magnitude faster :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To improve the performance of the code suggested by @Divakar even further, I would rather suggest to use [PyTorch](http://pytorch.org/) library. This would give you over 2 orders of magnitude speedup when compared to plain the *dot product* (`np.dot()`) using [NumPy arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) (for your case, from `ms` to microseconds; more on this later)

First, I will demonstrate how to do it in NumPy and [PyTorch](http://pytorch.org/). (Since [*PyTorch*](http://pytorch.org/) shares the same memory of [NumPy *ndarray*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html), there's no extra work we've to do)

---

**Timings**

```
# setup inputs
In [61]: d = np.random.multivariate_normal(
    ...:     [0.0,
    ...:      0.0,
    ...:      0.0,
    ...:      0.0,
    ...:      0.0
    ...:      ],
    ...:     np.array([
    ...:         [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    ...:         [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    ...:         [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    ...:         [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
    ...:         [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1]
    ...:     ]),
    ...:     int(1e5)
    ...: )

In [62]: d.dtype
Out[62]: dtype('float64')

In [63]: D = np.array([[1, 10, 0, 0], 
    ...:           [0, 1, 0, 0],
    ...:           [0, 0, 1, 0],
    ...:           [0, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=np.float64)
    ...:           

In [64]: DT = D.T

In [65]: DT.dtype
Out[65]: dtype('float64')


# create input tensors in PyTorch
In [66]: d_tensor = torch.DoubleTensor(d[:, 0:4])

In [67]: DT_tensor = torch.DoubleTensor(DT)

# float64 tensors
In [69]: type(d_tensor), type(DT_tensor)
Out[69]: (torch.DoubleTensor, torch.DoubleTensor)

# dot/matmul using `np.dot()`
In [73]: np_dot = np.dot(d[:, 0:4], DT)

# matmul using `torch.matmul()`
In [74]: torch_matmul = torch.matmul(d_tensor, DT_tensor)

# sanity check!! :)
In [75]: np.allclose(np_dot, torch_matmul)
Out[75]: True
```

---

Now the timings are here for different approaches!

```
In [5]: %timeit r = np.einsum('ij,kj->ik', d[:, 0:4], D)
2.63 ms ± 97.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [6]: %timeit r = d[:, 0:4].dot(D.T)
1.56 ms ± 47.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [7]: %timeit r = np.einsum('ij,kj->ik', d[:, 0:4], D, optimize=True)
2.73 ms ± 136 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# over 2 orders of magnitude faster :)
In [14]: %timeit torch_matmul = torch.matmul(d_tensor, DT_tensor)
87 µs ± 7.71 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

An important thing to take care is that we need to have **same datatype** in both [NumPy ndarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) and [PyTorch](http://pytorch.org/) Tensors. (Here I used `np.float64` since `np.random.multivariate_normal` returned `float64` values. So, I upcasted the `D` matrix to `float64`. Correspondingly, when creating [PyTorch](http://pytorch.org/) tensors, I used [`torch.DoubleTensor`](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/tensors.html#torch-tensor) which is equivalent to `np.float64`. This is kind of **datatype match is essential** to have the same result, particularly when dealing with floating point numbers).

---

So, the key takeaway is that [PyTorch Tensor](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/tensors.html#torch-tensor) operations are *orders of magnitude faster* than [NumPy ndarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) operations.

Comment: Seems very interesting, I don't have a nVidia GPU on my machine, but I'll test asap. (or is it supposed to work with Radeon? - I have the same performance as numpy with MKL)

Comment: @CedricH. As of now, since all these frameworks are designed to support CUDA/CuDNN based nVidia GPU, I'm not sure about Radeon, unfortunately.